# Top align an aspect filled image in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

**Update: I have simplified the example and code and provided an image**

I have a stack layout containing two images. The first image is just to show the entire image. The second image has a fixed height and image aspect is set to AspectFill. I see the middle part of the second image but would like to see the top part. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Here is the XAML

```
<StackLayout Spacing="20">

    <Image Source="darth.jpg" />

    <Image Source="darth.jpg"
           HeightRequest="100"
           Aspect="AspectFill" />

</StackLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like. I want the second image to show the top part of the image, not the middle part.

[image]

Comment: It may be go by managing or scaling the image using the dependency service.

Comment: Did you skip copying the RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions in creating the question? I don't know if it's relevant to your question, but a Grid without those seems strange. But maybe more important, have you tried a RelativeLayout?

Comment: just use a stacklayout

Comment: It's nothing to do with the parent layout. I have re-authored the question to remove the grid and custom control from the issue. It is to do with the way the image control handles aspect fill along with a fixed height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no code in Xamarin.Forms `Image` implementation, which adjusts the position of image with `Aspect.AspectFill`, so you have two options here:

1. Try to add an extra wrap with `HeightRequest="100"` around the second image, and remove `HeightRequest="100"` and `Aspect="AspectFill"` from it.
2. Implement your own `ImageRenderer` for the target platform following this [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/view/).

Comment: Tried adding an extra wrap. Didn't work. Pretty sure the built in image renderers center the image when the image control height is smaller than the actual image height. Custom renderer seems to be the way to go unfortunately.

Comment: Hey @SteveChadbourne, I know this is from a while ago, but did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: Hey @Steve sorry I made no further progress on this.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the HeightRequest on the Image, that will cause Xamarin.Forms to do the clipping, and there doesn't seem to be anything you can do about it. However if you wrap it in a ScrollView with a HeightRequest of 100, it will render as you want:

```
var image = new Image()
{
    Source = "darth.jpg",
    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill
};
var imageWrap = new ScrollView()
{
    HeightRequest = 100,
    Content = image
};
```

This has the added functionality that the user will be able to scroll through the image. Depending on the context, this may not be desirable. Plus, according to [Xamarin documentation](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scroll-view/):

> ScrollViews should not be nested. ScrollViews should not be nested
>   with other controls that provide scrolling, like ListView and WebView.

Comment: It does not work quite well in all cases. Works on iOS as expected. However, on Android, it's working only if source bitmap is larger than the width of Image control. If it's smaller, than it clips the content in such a way, that you cannot view all of it even with scrolling.